# Geometry nodes can't access vertex group

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have one object with two geometry nodes setups. The First can access vertex groups and the second cannot. What is the reason? Please help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that I replaced original geometry with generated one.
Vertex groups appear only when I join original geometry with generated, and I have to leave at least one vertex of the original geometry. Oherwise it will not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mlMl.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Geometry nodes can sometimes be janky, have you tried manually typing the name of the vertex group? Also, name your vertex groups, stay organised :D